# Swift: How to send data from loginView to other views?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a loginView and can switch to other views with an slide-out-menu with the SWRevealController.

The storyboard looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hicfe.jpg

I get a token with alamofire in the loginViewController and want to send it to the mainPageView with prepareForSegue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "logInSegue") {
        PersonResource.getToken(username: usernameTF.text!, password: passwordTF.text!){ token in
            let mainPageVC = segue.destination as! MainPageViewController                
            mainPageVC.token = token
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on login I get this error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your login code to this:

```
func login(){

        PersonResource.getToken(username: usernameTF.text!, password: passwordTF.text!){ token in
                        if let t = token as? String{
                            performSegue(with:"logInSegue", sender:token)
                        }
                }
}
```

and after you retrieve token from API you'll perform your segue with "logInSegue"

and you need to modify your prepare function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "logInSegue") {
        if let token = sender as? String{
                    let mainPageVC = segue.destination as! MainPageViewController                
          mainPageVC.token = token
                }
    }
```

basically you need to perform your segue after you retrieve token.

Comment: there is still a problem 
the destination of the segue a SWRevealController so i cant just create a segue.destination as MainPageViewController

Comment: Did you connect segue from button? If you do that can you remove it and create a segue from view to view.